# Getting Error while creating sample react-native project

Tags: react-native

On window machine i am trying to create new react native project , i am facing error.

tried with all commands:
react-native init WindowApp 0.61.0
npx react-native init WindowApp 0.61.0

[image]

Comment: Can you add the logs as code, which is recommended as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstalled yarn package , as both yarn and npm was installed .

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs command prompt run the following command. its occurred because of running behind a proxy error.

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

However, note that -g means it is set globally. To be a little safer, one could leave it off and run `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false` only if and when needed.